# How to change vendor preset in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I noticed the vendor preset for systemd services, and after researching I only found that distributions specify *.preset files to set vendor presets, but I cannot find it in ubuntu 22.04. Does Ubuntu define any such preset file where one can change the vendor presets?

Comment: So you don't have `/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-systemd.preset` and `/usr/lib/systemd/user-preset/90-systemd.preset` on your system?

Comment: Thank you, do those determine all systemd service paths, including `/etc/systemd`?

Answer (score 0):

systemd presets determine if a service should be enabled or disabled by default when it is installed.  Unless you are making your own distro, there is not much of a reason to change the presets.

Presumably you don't want to change the preset but the actual service status itself.  For example, either

```
systemd enable something.service
```

or

```
systemd disable something.service
```

or maybe

```
systemd enable --now something.service
```

Editing the preset files directly is a bad idea, as the next update may replace those files and undo your changes.  The commands above are permanent (and in the case of `--now` also immediate).

Comment: I understand, but looking at understanding ubuntu a bit more. I also want to know where continue my own reading, met a small deadlock on google and even chatgpt who answered almost identically to your own answer, like so many before.
Since I did not see corresponding directories for each of the sysmted paths, I wanted to continue there.

Comment: man page for systemd.preset may be helpful.  There's several other systemd commands (info? status?) that might be helpful but probably not.  I believe the systemd website might have more information, more geared towards people who are making distros that is probably closer to what you want.